# Add HTML elements to DOM with JQuery nicely

Tags: jquery, html, syntax, append, jsx

At the moment, I add elements to the DOM with append with html inside of double quotes, this can become incredibly messy and very hard to read especially if you have variables inside of it, in React you would use JSX which is clean, is there a way to use JSX in an normal JQuery script or something like JSX?

Comment: what have you tried so far? please share it

Comment: @bhushan kawadkar, nothing as of yet as I can't seem to find a solution than to do a messy string of html and variables.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Not every question is bad without code. This is actually a pretty interesting subject. Might be fun to write a jQuery plugin who can do that if there is non yet.

Comment: This problem is very annoying when you're working with an API endpoints getting post objects, you then need to construct the post without JQuery to then be appended to a post container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, two options:

1. Template literals
2. JSX

#### Template literals

In modern JavaScript, you can use template literals rather than string literals, and they can include placeholders with JavaScript expressions in them:

```js
let counter = 0;

$(`<table class="main">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell ${counter++}</td>
            <td>Cell ${counter++}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell ${counter++}</td>
            <td>Cell ${counter++}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`).appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There's still some awkwardness, definitely, but it's a lot better than string literals.

More on template literals [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

#### JSX

JSX is not limited to React. It has its [own specification](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) and multiple implementations, such as [`jsx-transform`](https://github.com/alexmingoia/jsx-transform).

For instance, here's a simple Node.js wrapper that uses it to transpile a file:

```
var jsx = require('jsx-transform');

console.log(jsx.fromFile("input.jsx", {
  factory: 'be'
}));
```

If `input.jsx` were:

```
let counter = 0;
let table =
    <table class="main">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell {counter++}</td>
                <td>Cell {counter++}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell {counter++}</td>
                <td>Cell {counter++}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>;
table.appendTo(document.body);
```

*(Note that that's `class="main"`, not `className="main"`. Using `className` instead is a React thing, to avoid an issue that hasn't been a problem since ES5 came out in 2009.)*

The output would be:

```
let counter = 0;
let table =
    be('table', {class: "main"}, [
        be('tbody', null, [
            be('tr', null, [
                be('td', null, ["Cell ", counter++]),
                be('td', null, ["Cell ", counter++])
            ]),
            be('tr', null, [
                be('td', null, ["Cell ", counter++]),
                be('td', null, ["Cell ", counter++])
            ])
        ])
    ]);
table.appendTo(document.body);
```

Notice how the JSX expressions have been converted into calls to the factory function (`be` in that example; React's factory function is `React.createElement`). All you have to do is supply the `be` function and integrate the transformer into your build chain (`jsx-transform` comes prebaked with the ability to plug into Browserify).

Your `be` using jQuery might look something like this:

```
function be(tagName, attributes, children) {
    const result = $("<" + tagName + "/>");
    if (attributes) {
        result.attr(attributes);
    }
    if (children) {
        if (Array.isArray(children)) {
            for (const child of children) {
                result.append(child);
            }
        } else {
            result.append(child);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Live Example of the be function using the transformed result:

```js
let counter = 0;
let table =
    be('table', {class: "main"}, [
        be('tbody', null, [
            be('tr', null, [
                be('td', null, ["Cell ", counter++]),
                be('td', null, ["Cell ", counter++])
            ]),
            be('tr', null, [
                be('td', null, ["Cell ", counter++]),
                be('td', null, ["Cell ", counter++])
            ])
        ])
    ]);
table.appendTo(document.body);

function be(tagName, attributes, children) {
    const result = $("<" + tagName + "/>");
    if (attributes) {
        result.attr(attributes);
    }
    if (children) {
        if (Array.isArray(children)) {
            for (const child of children) {
                result.append(child);
            }
        } else {
            result.append(child);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Surprisingly, it really is about that simple.

Comment: Templates literals seems to be the way forward for me, but the JSX implementation looks interesting. Thanks!